# How can I run xunit test in F#

Tags: f#, xunit.net

I have Xunit and Xunit(Runner: Visual Studio) installed and he is my simple test:

```
namespace Testing

    module Tests =
        open Xunit
        open Xunit.Extensions

        [<Fact>]
        let ``just test`` =
                Assert.Equal(1, 1)
                ()
```

But I can find Xunit in Test -> Window -> Test explorer and Resharper Unit Tests Window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like your test is missing the [unit type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx), `()`, to identify it as a function taking no arguments. If you write your test like this it should show up in the Visual Studio Test Explorer.

```
[<Fact>]
let ``just test`` () =
    Assert.Equal(1, 1)
```

Comment: Seems like it. This is a mistake I do all the time and always feel incredibly stupid afterwards.